# Modeling multiple relationship ERD and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-relationship, erd

I am new in databases and I have to model a relationship between two entity sets: Bookings and Users. I created two relationhips between them (many-to-many and one-to-many) like
[image]

In SQL I created 3 tables: Booking, Users and junction table Booking_Users like i

[image]

In short what I want to achieve: one user can make multiple bookings. One booking can be for several people and they are added to Users table. Each user can be associated with several booking. I have to store an information about who is responsible for a booking (there is a foreign key User_id in Bookings table) and to which booking users are assigned (this information is stored in junction table).
My question is, is it a good way to model such a relationship?

Comment: Be careful. Terminology can be confusing and misleading but it also gives you information you can overlook. "A user can make a booking" is not the same as "a booking can be for several people". To me those are two distinct sets of information. The person making the booking is not necessarily one of the persons for which the booking exists in some fashion". A travel agent will make lots of bookings for many different people but the booking is not **for** the agent.

Answer (score 1):

That's ok.  The weakness there is that it doesn't enforce a rule that the "Primary user" is one of the "booking users".  You can enforce that by making the Foreign Key from Booking to Booking_User(BookingId,UserId), but that complicates the DML a bit as you can't set the primary user until you've added the Booking_user.

The common alternative design is to add an IsPrimary column to the Bookings_Users junction table.  But both designs are pretty common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't mentioned it before, but the fact that "the "Primary user" is one of the "booking users" is one of the requirements for this database. 
Which is a better practice - my solution or adding IsPrimary column? Or maybe that are just as good?